# How to delete files ,subdirectory entirely to specified path

Tags: c#

I have created directory and its subdirectory and files... I have to delete them entirely.
Is there any possible ways.How can i achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Directory.Delete("the dir", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx

Comment: You are missing a comma between the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I guess,

```
Directory.Delete(path, true /* recursive */);
```

will do the job.